# How to build Prolog grammar parse tree consisting of two sentences joined by a conjunction

Tags: prolog, dcg

I have following Prolog code to recognise a sentence. Notice that it builds a parse tree for the grammar too.

```
sentence(plural,s(Np,Vp)) -->
   noun_phrase(plural,Np),
   verb_phrase(plural,Vp).
sentence(singular,s(Np,Vp)) -->
   noun_phrase(singular,Np),
   verb_phrase(singular,Vp).
```

I need to have a predicate that can recognise a compound sentence (it consists of two sentences joined by a conjunction). I came up with following code but execution fails. Of course, in my Prolog code there are definitions for noun_phrase, verb_phrase and so on.

```
compound_sentence(comp_s(s1,Conj,s2)) -->
   sentence(_,s1(Np,Vp)),
   conjuction(_,Conj),
   sentence(_,s2(Np,Vp)).
```

e.g. When I run this query, it will fail.

```
?- phrase(compound_sentence(_),
          [the,reboot,is,a,success,and,the,user,does,a,save]).
```

How do you go about detecting compound sentences?

Comment: Does it fail or enter an infinite loop? What happens when you use `trace`?

Answer (score 0):

The reason why query fails:

```
phrase(compound_sentence(_), ...)
```

because (a) the two subgoals sentence(*, s1(Np,Vp)) cannot match the parse tree sentence/2 is building: sentence(*, s(Np,Vp)). And (b) the two sentences cannot have the same Np and Vp. Try something like this:

```
compound_sentence(comp_s(S1,Conj,S2)) -->
   sentence(_, S1),
   conjuction(_,Conj),
   sentence(_, S2).
```

where S1 = s(Np1, Vp1) corresponding to the first sentence, and S2 = s(Np2, Vp2) for the second.